# Display GridView Cell Value through Intellisense

Tags: c#, debugging, gridview, intellisense

While debugging what's the way to access to certain row's certain column's value through Intellisense?

After the "Rows", which one to go for?

[image]

Comment: Assign the value of this cell a variable and see it on debug window? Like `string s = Gridview1.Rows[rownumber].Cells[columnnumber].Text;` ?

Comment: Good one. Edited my answer. Pls see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a little confusing that the "plus" sign doesn't show up next to "Results View" by default.

You have to click on the circular arrows icon next to "Results View" *(seen in your image)* to enumerate the collection of rows.

Then a plus sign will appear next to Results View, which you can click to show another drop-down with your `DataRow` objects.

[image]